# Multiple "close" buttons on modal

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I am using the modals found [here on Codrops](http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/).

These modals have one close button (also closes when you click outside the modal), but I want to add more. The JavaScript is below:

```
var ModalEffects = (function() {

    function init() {

        var overlay = document.querySelector( '.md-overlay' );

        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

            var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
                close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );

            function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

                if( hasPerspective ) {
                    classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }
            }

            function removeModalHandler() {
                removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
            }

            el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
                overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
                overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

                if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                    }, 25 );
                }
            });

            close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                removeModalHandler();
            });

        } );

    }

    init();

})();
```

I thought by just simply swapping:

```
close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );
```

With this:

```
close = modal.querySelectorAll( '.md-close' );
```

would do the trick -- and every element with the **md-close** class would close the modal. I was wrong (I'm new to JavaScript if you couldn't tell).

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

**Updated Code:**

```
var ModalEffects = (function() {

    function init() {

        var overlay = document.querySelector( '.md-overlay' );

        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

            var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) );

            function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

                if( hasPerspective ) {
                    classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }
            }

            function removeModalHandler() {
                removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
            }

            el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
                overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
                overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

                if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                    }, 25 );
                }
            });

            modal.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                if (classie.has(ev.target, "md-close")) {
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                    removeModalHandler();
                }
            });


        } );

    }

    init();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that `addEventListener` only works on a single element at a time and `close` is a collection of elements. You're probably better off adding an event listener to the modal itself and checking for the `md-close` class:

```
modal.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    if (classie.has(ev.target, "md-close")) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        removeModalHandler();
    }
});
```

Then you can ditch your `close = ...` variable as well.

Comment: Hey Brad, thanks so much for taking a crack at this, but still not having any luck (or maybe I added your code wrong). Here's what I've got... If you see anything that might be causing it to not work, just let me know. I owe you!

**Updated code above.**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
            close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            removeModalHandler();
        });
```

Into

```
            document.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            if (classie.has(ev.target, "md-close")) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                removeModalHandler();
            }
        });
```

And it will works!

NOW... I thought applying this hack solved also my problem as I wanted to add .md-close on my .md-trigger link to close a modal and open a new one but it didn't work! Someone could help me on this?

[How to display a new modal window hiding the previous one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972166/how-to-display-a-new-modal-window-hiding-the-previous-one)

Thanks!