# How to display a new modal window hiding the previous one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, modeless

Using [tympanus.net](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/) modals (with greats animations) is easy to delete the backdrop div (`<div class="md-overlay"></div>`)letting me interact with menu items behind my modal but I don't know how to display just one modal at time as when I open a new one the previous  still there and the new appear over it.

Everything is controlled from a class `.md-show` which is applied to the called modal.
I think what I need to do is delete all `.md-show` class applied before opening a new one with this same class. Maybe with a script?

UPDATE:
This is the script: Copyright 2013, Codrops //sorry, I can't place comments! They doesn't works!

```
var ModalEffects = (function() {

    function init() {

        var overlay = document.querySelector( '.md-overlay' );

        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

            var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
                close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );

            function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

                if( hasPerspective ) {
                    classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }
            }

            function removeModalHandler() {
                removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
            }

            el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
                overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
                overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

                if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                    }, 25 );
                }
            });

            close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                removeModalHandler();
            });

        } );

    }

    init();

})();
```

I Think I need to remove `.md-show` here, before opening the new modal:

```
 el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
            overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
            overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

            if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }, 25 );
            }
        });
```

I made some tries without any success so some help will be appreciate! :) [tympanus referring article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/25/nifty-modal-window-effects/)

Comment: Use this version of Modal and it's easy! http://kjantzer.github.io/backbonejs-modal-view/

Answer (score 0):

Found a funny solution using mousedown and mouseup events!

mousedown will delete all md-show classes
mouseup will add md-show

Easy but it took me 4 days to reach that without any knowledge on scripts!

FULL RIGHT CODE!

```
var ModalEffects = (function() {
    function init() {

    var overlay = document.querySelector( '.md-overlay' );

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

        var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
            close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );

        function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
            classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

            if( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
            }
        }

        function removeModalHandler() {
            removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
        }

        el.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function( ev ) {
            classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
            overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
            overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

            if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }, 25 );
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function( ev ) {
            if (classie.has(ev.target, "md-close")) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                removeModalHandler();
            }
        });

    } );

}

init();
```

})();

Please note that you need to add md-close class to md-trigger links!